# How can I get values from function that is inside of class?

Tags: java, function, class, return

I want to get some values from one function inside of different class and use it on Main class. But it seems like I am doing somethings wrong.

```
public class test {

public static int enkucukbul ( double[] x){ // this method finds the smallest index
    return IntStream.range(0, x.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> i)
            .min(Comparator.comparing(i -> x[i]))
            .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}


public static double tabu(double x, int isayi) {

    Random rrandom = new Random();

    float r;


    double[] fxdizi = new double[4];      
    double[] xdizi = new double[4];       
    double[] hareket = new double[4];     


    for (int j = 0; j < isayi; j++) {

        r = rrandom.nextFloat(); 


        hareket[0] = x + 2 * r; 
        hareket[1] = x + 4 * r;
        hareket[2] = x - 2 * r;
        hareket[3] = x - 4 * r;

        xdizi[0] = hareket[0]; 
        xdizi[1] = hareket[1];
        xdizi[2] = hareket[2];
        xdizi[3] = hareket[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            if (xdizi[i] <= 1) {
                fxdizi[i] = xdizi[i] * xdizi[i];
            } else {
                fxdizi[i] = Math.pow((xdizi[i] - 3), 2) - 3;
            }

        } // for dongusu


        int minIndex = enkucukbul(fxdizi); // found the smallest index

        return x;
        return minIndex;
        return j;
        return xdizi[minIndex];
        return fxdizi[minIndex];

        x = xdizi[minIndex]; // we found the smallest x


    }  // all things

 }
}
```

Also my Main class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    test ts = new test();
    System.out.println(ts.tabu(7.26,2));

 }
}
```

I just want to get the values in return statements like x, j ...etc. But I get error **"java:unreachable statement"** on every return statement and also **"java:missing return statement"** in the end. Where do i do wrong?

Extra Note: I'm sorry for the localized variable names since this is my optimization class assignment

Comment: The functions are Static. You should call them with test.batu() without creating an object of the class test. Or remove ‘static’ from your function. + you cannot return multiple values like you did.

Comment: Just as an aside, 1) whenever you come across using `mapToObj` and return the same value as the input argument then you _should_ use `boxed()`. 2) returning `Integer.MIN_VALUE` in the case of the source array being empty is fine but I'd try to follow the typical approach of returning `-1`. 3) prefer `comparingDouble` instead of `comparing` when comparing primitive doubles as it's more efficient. `return IntStream.range(0, x.length)
                .boxed()
                .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(i -> x[i]))
                .orElse(-1);`

Answer (score 1):

In java a method can have only *one* return statement. You can't have more than one return statement per method unless used in an `if-else` block.

As the compiler tells you the remaining statements are unreachable after the first return statement.

As per your latest comment, you can create a wrapper class to hold multiple values that you want to return. For eg :

```
class Calculation {
    public double a;
    public double b;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Now from your method you could capture the values of the variables and then store them in an object of the class created above :

```
public static Calculation tabu(double x, int y) {
    Calculation cal = new Calculation();

    // do something with x and y and other things

    cal.setA(x);
    cal.setB(y);

    return cal;
}
```

Comment: So is there a way that i can get multiple variables from the function instead of just one?

Answer (score 1):

You've wrote multiple return statements in following lines :

```
return x;
return minIndex;
return j;
return xdizi[minIndex];
return fxdizi[minIndex];
```

It is not acceptable in java.

Also you are missing return value at the end of method `tabu`outside of for loop. I see several logical mistakes in your code.

You need to refactor your code, also if you can explain what you are trying to achieve it will be much more clear.

Comment: I want to get values that i stated on the top and use it in my main class. My main objective is list them on some kind of JTable.

Comment: So as I understand you want to return all your variables, why don't you define a class which wraps your variables and return that single object from your tabu method? Move your variables into a class for ex. `CalculationResult`and return it from your tabu method.

Comment: That's a really good idea. I will definetly try that. Çok teşekkürler!